# нужно при показе определенного изображения выводить на экран определенную информацию

Tags: c#, unity3d, augmented-reality

я использую Unity 2020.2.6f1, и скажу прямо - например если я навожусь камерой на портрет например Шекспира, то мне на экране должно появиться немного информации про этого писателя, если я навожусь камерой на Пушкина, то мне выдается информация по нему. Пожалуйста, кто знает, подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Обучить нейронку например.

Comment: Повесить коллайдер на портреты и определить нужное поведение (вывод или включение текста) в [OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html)

Comment: Вы пробовали что-то сделать? Я вам очень рекомендую изначально пробовать найти решения в интернете, попробовать сделать что-то самому, и после уже идти на SO, и описать, что пробовали, и что у вас не получилось. В целом же вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы! проблема решена!

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать скрипт,в котором будет динамический массив объектов( картин )и чтобы через рейкаст из камеры можно было определять на какой объект смотришь и выводить информацию в UI.

Comment: Вы - новый участник SO, так что я советую почитать, [как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Это важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем, удачи!

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы! проблема решена!